# Stash does not have enough balance to bond

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am getting this issue while running node using `./target/release/node-template --dev`  this command. I try to change `GenesisConfig -> balance` same as substrate example from [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e0059a416a5768e58765a49b33c21920c0b0eb9/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L299) and add `GenesisConfig -> staking` like [this](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/6e0059a416a5768e58765a49b33c21920c0b0eb9/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L315) in my node but I am getting issue. Someone please help what is wrong here.

[image]

[code link](https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/tree/staking-pallet-testing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://github.com/XcavateBlockchain/MarketplaceMVP_Substrate/blob/b4e1b56ac1a6757f79595d9fe291d5f3fd990798/node/src/chain_spec.rs#L63-L76

```rs
// Initial PoA authorities
vec![
    authority_keys_from_seed("Alice"),
    authority_keys_from_seed("Bob"),
    authority_keys_from_seed("Charlie"),
    authority_keys_from_seed("Dave"),
],
// Sudo account
get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
// Pre-funded accounts
vec![
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Alice"),
    get_account_id_from_seed::<sr25519::Public>("Bob"),
],
```

You only funded Alice and Bob. Hence, Charlie and Dave don't have enough money to bond.

---

*I'm very happy to answer your question. But maybe you should pay more patient with your code?
You got a pretty clear code comment, you shouldn't miss it... :)*

Comment: thank you I will try to follow what you are saying from now.